# Scan thousands of paper form responses, and export all information into a sheet

Tags: automation, ocr, scanning, spreadsheet

I have a thousand handwritten responses to the following paper form:

[image: Document]

I need to scan them (I have a scanner) and export all the data in a table like this:

[image: Sheet]

Is this possible? With an OCR? With LATEX? With Python? With a Windows software? I'm open to all answers.
There is no problem if the document has to be transformed and for example the text fields are large boxes or you have to write letters in capitals.

Answer (score 0):

You may discover a number of OCR (Optical Character Recognition) programs which will perform in the manner you require. I used a search term set "ocr form scanning" (which could be improved) and many results were returned.

One of them is an [Amazon Web Services product](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) called Textract which explicitly describes your task:

> Amazon Textract is a machine learning (ML) service that automatically
> extracts text, handwriting, and data from scanned documents. It goes
> beyond simple optical character recognition (OCR) to identify,
> understand, and extract data from forms and tables. Today, many
> companies manually extract data from scanned documents such as PDFs,
> images, tables, and forms, or through simple OCR software that
> requires manual configuration (which often must be updated when the
> form changes). To overcome these manual and expensive processes,
> Textract uses ML to read and process any type of document, accurately
> extracting text, handwriting, tables, and other data with no manual
> effort. You can quickly automate document processing and act on the
> information extracted, whether you’re automating loans processing or
> extracting information from invoices and receipts. Textract can
> extract the data in minutes instead of hours or days. Additionally,
> you can add human reviews with Amazon Augmented AI to provide
> oversight of your models and check sensitive data.

This may not be the singular answer to your goal, but it shows that the resources are available and may be found with appropriate search terms.